# How to convert a javascript object array file to customized json file

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm getting a javascript object array. I'm trying to write it to json file by replacing certain params. i don't require comma separated between every object and need to insert a new json object before every existing object.
current js object is

```
[{name:"abc", age:22},
 {name:"xyz", age:32,
 {name:"lmn", age:23}]
```

the expected json output file is,

```
{"index":{}}
{name:"abc", age:22}
{"index":{}}
{name:"xyz", age:32}
{"index":{}}
{name:"lmn", age:23}
```

My code is

```
sourceData = data.map((key) => key['_source'])
const strData = JSON.stringify(sourceData);
const newStr = strData.replace("},{", "}\n{");
const newStr2 = newStr.replace(`{"name"`, `{"index" : {}}\n{"name"`);
fs.writeFile('data.json', newStr2, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("JSON data is saved.");
});
```

But in my output only the first object is changing. I need this to happen my entire output json file. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd insert dummy objects first and then map `stringify` over the result:

```js
array = [
    {name: "abc", age: 22},
    {name: "xyz", age: 32},
    {name: "lmn", age: 23}]


result = array
    .flatMap(item => [{index: {}}, item])
    .map(x => JSON.stringify(x))
    .join('\n')

console.log(result)

// fs.writeFileSync('path/to/file', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the result isn't JSON (but it looks like valid JSON-Lines).

I wouldn't try to do string manipulation on the result of `JSON.stringify`. JSON is too complex for manipulation with basic regular expressions.

Instead, since you're outputting the contents of the array, handle each array entry separately:

```js
const ws = fs.createWriteStream("data.json");
sourceData = data.map((key) => key['_source'])
for (const entry of sourceData) {
    const strData = JSON.stringify(entry);
    ws.write(`{"index":{}}\n${strData}\n`);
}
ws.end();
console.log("JSON data is saved.");
```

Live Example (obviously not writing to a file):

```js
const sourceData = [
    {name:"abc", age:22},
    {name:"xyz", age:32},
    {name:"lmn", age:23}
];
for (const entry of sourceData) {
    const strData = JSON.stringify(entry);
    console.log(`{"index":{}}\n${strData}`); // Left off the trailing \n because console.log breaks up the lines
}
console.log("JSON data is saved.");
```

Comment: the data.json file is empty. FYI i need the exact syntax, though it's not a perfect json file

Comment: @MohamedAhkam - I should have been calling `end()` rather than `destroy()`. But if you want to build the entire string first and then write it, you can do it georg's way.